# Use XPath to select an element that doesn't have an img tag as a child

Tags: xpath

Is it possible to select an h1 tag that does not contain any img tags with a single line XPath expression? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `not` operator and the `descendent` axis to catch h1 tags without even a distant img child.

```
//h1[not(descendant::img)]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`not()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-not) function:

```
//h1[not(descendant::img)]
```

Comment: This appears to be the cleanest solution, but it will not check if an img tag exists that is a child of a child of an h1 tag. Is it possible to check recursively through each child of the h1 tag and their children to ensure that there is no img tag?

Comment: Well, the `not()` argument is also just a XPath, you can use anything there. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, your updated solution is just what I was looking for but Andrew Arnott beat you to it :P

Answer (score 4):

```
//h1[count(img) = 0]
```

I assume this is for XHTML, otherwise no XPath.

Comment: This works if the img tag is a direct child of <h1>. Is it possible to check if there is no img tag at any level within the h1 tag?

Answer (score 1):

To find an `h1` element with no `img` child:

```
//h1[not(img)]
```

To find an `h1` element with no `img` descendant:

```
//h1[not(.//img)]
```

or

```
//h1[not(descendant::img)]
```

which might be easier to understand when reading your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following XPath expression:

```
//h1[count(img) = 0]
```